# Why is smallest singular value of a singular matrix zero?

Tags: matrices

In my  book, it is stated that the smallest singular value ($\sigma_n$ ) of a singular matrix is zero. I don't understand what it is so, please someone explain the reason to me.

Comment: What about the identity matrix?

Comment: What book is that?

Comment: The statement seems to need one more or one fewer "non".

Comment: Probably it is a typo - they meant to say the smallest singular value of a singular matrix must be zero.  In fact, the smallest singular value of a non-singular matrix must always be non-zero.  So just like Andreas said - it needs one fewer or one more "non".

Comment: Picture or it did not happen :).

Comment: @Tom: I made a mistake, sorry.

Comment: You're right @StephenMontgomery-Smith, I translated the statement into English and made that mistake. It was "singular" matrix.